# Spring Security LDAP get User Given Name

Tags: spring, spring-security-ldap

I am using Spring security 3.2.4  with Windows AD LDAP.
I am able to successfully authenticate and LdapUserDetailsImpl  is populated.
From LdapUserDetailsImpl  I can get the username, authorities, but how to get the employee name (not the login user name)
LdapUserDetailsImpl contains following properties and values

```
Username = 40000 , 
Enabled = true,
AccountNonExpired = true,
Dn: cn=employee name,ou=IT_FM,ou=XXX_USERS,dc=XXXX,dc=CO,dc=IN;
```

How do it get the employee name,  Do I need to extend some class and write my own mapping or
may be simply get Dn from the principal and split the string to get the employee name.

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/57457-ldap-custom-userdetails

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov thanks for the link. I understand that we need to write or own implementation, but I was thinking, if we have more simple way. Any way I have implemented my context mapper and added it as answer. Is that the correct way to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the Dn from Principal and extract the username (cn)

```
LdapUserDetailsImpl ldapDetails = (LdapUserDetailsImpl) SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
String dn = ldapDetails.getDn();
int beginIndex = dn.indexOf("cn=") + 3;
int endIndex = dn.indexOf(",");
String username = dn.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mukun almost has this. The only thing is, instead of:

```
String dn = ldapUserDetailsImpl.getDn();
int beginIndex = dn.indexOf("cn=") + 3;
int endIndex = dn.indexOf(",");
myUserDetails.setEmployeeName(dn.substring(beginIndex, endIndex));
```

I would have:

```
String name = ctx.getObjectAttribute("cn").toString()
myUserDetails.setEmployeeName(name)
```

This lets LDAP integration handle all the horrible stuff for you and loses the danger of chopping up strings yourself.

You might also consider

```
myUserDetails.setFirstName(ctx.getObjectAttribute("givenName").toString())
myUserDetails.setLastName(ctx.getObjectAttribute("sn").toString())
```

These things should work for both MS AD, "normal" LDAP and possible Novell too.

So the **full** answer would be:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsContextMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {
    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        LdapUserDetailsImpl ldapUserDetailsImpl = (LdapUserDetailsImpl) super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, authorities);
        MyUserDetails myUserDetails = new MyUserDetails();
        myUserDetails.setAccountNonExpired(ldapUserDetailsImpl.isAccountNonExpired());
        myUserDetails.setAccountNonLocked(ldapUserDetailsImpl.isAccountNonLocked());
        myUserDetails.setCredentialsNonExpired(ldapUserDetailsImpl.isCredentialsNonExpired());
        myUserDetails.setEnabled(ldapUserDetailsImpl.isEnabled());
        myUserDetails.setUsername(ldapUserDetailsImpl.getUsername());
        myUserDetails.setAuthorities(ldapUserDetailsImpl.getAuthorities());
        myUserDetails.setEmployeeName(ctx.getObjectAttribute("cn").toString());
        return myUserDetails;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Custom Mapper. Is this correct way of doing ?

```
 @Service
    public class MyUserDetailsContextMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {
        @Override
        public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
            LdapUserDetailsImpl ldapUserDetailsImpl = (LdapUserDetailsImpl) super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, authorities);
            MyUserDetails myUserDetails = new MyUserDetails();
            myUserDetails.setAccountNonExpired(ldapUserDetailsImpl.isAccountNonExpired());
            myUserDetails.setAccountNonLocked(ldapUserDetailsImpl.isAccountNonLocked());
            myUserDetails.setCredentialsNonExpired(ldapUserDetailsImpl.isCredentialsNonExpired());
            myUserDetails.setEnabled(ldapUserDetailsImpl.isEnabled());
            myUserDetails.setUsername(ldapUserDetailsImpl.getUsername());
            myUserDetails.setAuthorities(ldapUserDetailsImpl.getAuthorities());
            String dn = ldapUserDetailsImpl.getDn();
            int beginIndex = dn.indexOf("cn=") + 3;
            int endIndex = dn.indexOf(",");
            myUserDetails.setEmployeeName(dn.substring(beginIndex, endIndex));
            return myUserDetails;
        }

    }
```